# NSPredicate: Fetch one of each kind

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I want to create an `NSFetchRequest` for objects like this:

The `Object` is `Car` which has an `attribute` `color`.
I have four cars:

```
car1.color = red
car2.color = red
car3.color = blue
car4.color = green
```

I want to create an `NSPredicate` that selects only one car for each color(it doesn't matter which car it selects.

How can I achieve this?

In fact I'm looking for something similar like a `DISTINCT` in SQL

Comment: there is in fact a way to get distinct results from Core Data. cf. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Core Data *does* support fetching distinct values. Apple even provides sample code here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html

---

From that page:

> ### Fetching Distinct Values
>
> To fetch the unique values of a particular attribute across all
>   instances of a given entity, you configure a fetch request with the
>   method setReturnsDistinctResults: (and pass YES as the parameter). You
>   also specify that the fetch should return dictionaries rather than
>   managed objects, and the name of the property you want to fetch.

**Swift 2.0**

```
let context:NSManagedObjectContext! = <#Get the context#>
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName( "<#Entity name#>",  inManagedObjectContext:context )
let request = NSFetchRequest()
request.entity = entity
request.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
request.returnsDistinctResults = true
request.propertiesToFetch = [ "<#Attribute name#>" ]

var objects:[[String:AnyObject]]?
do
{
    try objects = context.executeFetchRequest( request )
}
catch
{
    // handle failed fetch
}
```

**Obj-C**

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = <#Get the context#>;  

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription  entityForName:@"<#Entity name#>" inManagedObjectContext:context];  
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]; 
[request setEntity:entity]; 
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES]; 
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"<#Attribute name#>"]];  

// Execute the fetch. 

NSError *error = nil; 
id requestedValue = nil; 
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; 
if (objects == nil) {
    // Handle the error. 
}
```

(One "gotcha" is that the results will be returned as dictionaries--if you need the objects you can do another fetch to get them by ID)

Answer (score 14):

Did you tried to use `valueForKeyPath` ? You can do something like that in the array that NSPredicate provide to you.

```
NSArray* distinctColors = [cars valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.color"];
```

It will return to you the distinct colors that you have, I do not know if it is what you want, but with the colors you can do something like @Anupdas told:

Answer (score 3):

If you are targeting iOS 4.0 or later and not using the Core-Data SQL store why not use `predicateWithBlock:`?

The following will generate the `NSFetchRequest` you want.

```
- (NSFetchRequest*) fetchRequestForSingleInstanceOfEntity:(NSString*)entityName groupedBy:(NSString*)attributeName
{
  __block NSMutableSet *uniqueAttributes = [NSMutableSet set];

  NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    if( [uniqueAttributes containsObject:[evaluatedObject valueForKey:attributeName]] )
      return NO;

    [uniqueAttributes addObject:[evaluatedObject valueForKey:attributeName]];
    return YES;
  }];

  NSFetchRequest *req = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];
  req.predicate = filter;

  return req;
}
```

You could then create a new method to execute the fetch and return the results you want.

```
- (NSArray*) fetchOneInstanceOfEntity:(NSString*)entityName groupedBy:(NSString*)attributeName
{
  NSFetchRequest *req = [self fetchRequestForSingleInstanceOfEntity:entityName groupedBy:attributeName];

  // perform fetch
  NSError *fetchError = nil;
  NSArray *fetchResults = [_context executeFetchRequest:req error:&fetchError];

  // fetch results
  if( !fetchResults ) {
    // Handle error ...
    return nil;
  }

  return fetchResults;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity =
[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Selected_data"
            inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicatecnName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"countries contains[cd] %@", Countryid];
NSPredicate *predicateLn = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"languages contains[cd] %@", languageid];
NSArray *subPredicates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:predicatecnName, predicateLn, nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];


[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSMutableArray *sendfd=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSError *error;
NSArray *array1 = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


if (array1 != nil) {


    for (Selected_data *sld in array1)
    {

        [sendfd addObject:sld.providers];
    }


}
else {

}
return sendfd;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Cars"];
    NSArray *arrayValues = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if (arrayValues.count != 0) {
     NSDictionary *result = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrayValues
                           forKeys:[arrayValues valueForKey:@"color"]];
     return [result allValues];
}
```