# How to get List from entity in CoreData with all items there is each item appears only once?

Tags: ios, core-data

In CoreData Model I have"customers" entity with follow columns: 
custostomer_id , name ,  city , phone

It has the follow data in it:

```
1                Mary        Los-Angeles     054-112233
2                John        New-York        054-334455
3                Anna        Los-Angeles     054-445566
```

How can I get the List of all cities of customers where each city appears only once. For above  example it should be {Los-Angeles, New-Yoirk}.

This is my code:

```
  AppDelegate * delegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = delegate.managedObjectContext ;
  NSEntityDescription *entityDescN = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"customers" inManagedObjectContext:context];
  NSFetchRequest *requestN = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  [requestN setEntity:entityDescN ];
  NSPredicate *predN = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"?????????????"];
  [requestN setPredicate:predN];
  NSArray * objectsN = [context executeFetchRequest: requestN error:&error];
```

I mean what should be instead of "???" in NSPredicate definition?
I tried to write this code also with NSExpression, but still didn't succeeded.

Comment: Read "Fetching Distinct Values" section https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424720/nspredicate-fetch-one-of-each-kind

Answer (score 0):

//write this string in predicate

```
NSPredicate *predN = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELECT city FROM customers GROUP BY  city"];
```